# Using a Custom Query for the Entities in Doctrine - Symfony Form

Tags: php, mysql, forms, symfony, doctrine-orm

I have two tables one is users like this

id _ username _ firstname _ lastname

and the other one is users_test

id _ user_id _ name

I'm trying in Symfony Form (UserTestType) to make a Custom Query to get the id from the first Entitiy (UsersType) and insert the id as a Value.
my code is like this:

```
$builder->add('user_id', EntityType::class, array(
    'class' => 'UserBundle:Users',
    'query_builder' => function (EntityRepository $er) {
        return $er->createQueryBuilder('u')
            ->orderBy('u.id', 'ASC');
    },
    'choice_label' => 'firstname',
    'choice_value' => 'id',
));
```

when i reload the page it says: Could not load type "Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\EntityType"

note: I'v used Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\EntityType;

I hope someone could help me to find my Problem.

Comment: did you import EntityRepository ?

Comment: yes i used it also

Comment: that's weird, is your class named UserBundle:Users, maybe it's named User without "s" at the end, i'm talking about the class not the table in the data base, that's a very common error, you should refer to the class name not the table name

Comment: Did you mean `use Symfony\Bridge\Doctrine\Form\Type\EntityType;` ?

Answer (score 0):

I just tried it out and you probally copy&paste the TextType from user/first/lastname and just changed the last part of the Namespace, which lead you to the namespace where TextType and many other Types are lying. (I did the exact same mistake and lost 2 minutes of my life)

For EntityType and DoctrineType, you need to use following namespace:

`use Symfony\Bridge\Doctrine\Form\Type\EntityType;`

Also if you didn't do it (I know you wrote you use it, but just in case), you should also use your User Entity Class like:

`use UserBundle\Entity\Users;`

(or using the Singular form `User`, which I would recommend so you have no struggling with singular/plural)

I also remember reading somewhere that it is recommended to use the FQCN via `::class` so you could think changing:

`'class' => 'UserBundle:Users',`

to

`'class' => Users::class,`